# How to get the sample rate info of a file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sample-rate

I'm trying to get the sample rate information of a file before uploading it to server, need to access this for some validation purpose on browser.

What I did so far

```js
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.files[0]);
reader.onload = function (event) {
  let buffer = reader.result;
  let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  let context = new AudioContext();
  context.decodeAudioData(buffer, function (buffer1) {
    console.log(buffer1.sampleRate);
  });
}
```

But this always gives some constant result regardless of file selected. Can anyone suggest what is wrong here or any other idea to achieve the same?

Comment: If the sample rate is too low, the WebAudioAPI up-samples directly... I wonder whether that will be affecting it?

Comment: Having a consistent `sampleRate` is not that uncommon.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more? @Steve-Cutter-Blades

Comment: Say you have a whole series of mp3 audio files for an audio book. All of those files would have been generated at a consistent sampleRate (44100 fairly common).

Comment: So the code that I'm using, is it looks fine? (If I need to get the sample rate information of a file) @Steve-Cutter-Blades

Comment: Yes, `sampleRate` is a property of the AudioBuffer returned from `AudioContext.decodeAudioData()`.

Comment: Okay but I'm bit confused why this sample rate is not matching with FFPROBE library output, any idea? @Steve-Cutter-Blades

Comment: I can't speak to FFPROBE, only the Web Audio API. You did it the right way in your code, so maybe what @LewisFarnworth said is the issue.

Comment: The output of `AudioContext.decodeAudioData()` is always the same sample rate, as it resamples the audio that gets decoded